# MySQL backend, and PHP front search algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have reasearched a couple of options for MySQL & php search on the web and StackOverflow, but have not found something that really fits my scenario. Let me explain.

My scenario:

1. I have a table (TABLE1) in MySQL that has indexed terms (e.g. McDonalds, Microsoft, etc). This table has over 3000000 records.
2. I then have generic string that the user can enter - e.g. "There is a company called MCDonalds in my neighbourhood".
3. What i would like to look for occurances in the user entered string for any terms in my mysql table. I have implemented this currently by traversing each of the 3 million records in TABLE1 to see if it is in the user entered string (entered by user through a PHP page).

3 approach works 'well' - but of course it does not scale and the performance sucks :)

Any suggestion or pointers to algorithms to solve such a problem.. in a scalable and algorithmically sound way?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try MySQL's `FULLTEXT` search capability. Try something like this:

```
SELECT whatever, whatever
  FROM TABLE1
 WHERE MATCH(terms_column) AGAINST('There is a company called McDonalds in my neighbourhood')
```

You'll probably get lots of false positive matches, but this is an efficient way to at least narrow down the search.

It worked for me on a list of US cities matching against phrases like "Im going back to New Orleans to wear the ball and chain" and "Chicago, New York, Detroit and its all on the same street.".

You will need a `FULLTEXT` index on the your `terms_column`. And your table may, depending on the version of MySQL you're using, need to be in the MyISAM storage method.

Comment: thank you Ollie - much appreciated! This is exactly what i was looking for.. not sure why it was classified as off-topic :(